# How to prove the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[a_n, b_n]}f(t)\cos nt dt=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Asssume that $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $(0,+\infty)$ and $[a_n, b_n]\subset (0,+\infty)$. How to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[a_n, b_n]}f(t)\cos nt dt=0？$$ Do we need put some additional conditions on the sequence $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: This is a variation of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma. The usual proof of the RLL is to approximate $f$ by a $C^1$ function with compact support, integrate by parts, etc. Those ideas should work here.